# When should I ask a debugging question here versus on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

The close reasons in the flag menu suggest that debugging questions are permitted so long as they contain enough information to be answerable:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

What are the pros and cons of asking a debugging question here on SQA&T versus on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several pros and cons with debugging questions here vs Stack Overflow. Here's a few that I can think of immediately:

**Pro**

- This group tends to be more focused on test-related debugging questions, and more willing to ask questions to help you find and overcome your problems
- Most of the people here are test professionals, who often have a different perspective than coding professionals
- The people in this group tend to be a bit more forgiving that the long-term members of Stack Overflow who have probably seen every beginner question imaginable and tend to expect more research and evidence than we do.

**Con**

- This is a small, fairly quiet group. If you're working with an uncommon tool or language, it's possible there aren't many people here who have worked with that tool or language, so you may be more likely to get a response from Stack Overflow
- This group tends to pick up a lot of beginners who ask beginner questions, and sometimes don't know what they don't know. Sometimes the answers you receive may not be the best answers because those trying to help aren't as familiar with the subject as the more experienced members who may be too busy at the time to answer you. Stack Overflow has such a huge community that they generally don't have this problem.
- Most of the community here are software test and quality professionals first, so many of us aren't all that familiar with code. That can be reflected in the questions and answers, which, code-wise aren't necessarily at the same level as the code-based questions on Stack Overflow.

Personally, I'd suggest you start here, and if you don't get the help you need within a week or so, try Stack Overflow.

Comment: If I start here, and get nothing after a week, should I cross-post it to Stack Overflow or wouldn't it be better to flag it to be migrated there?

Comment: It would be better to flag it for migration.